# how to use sed command to search and replace recursively in subdirectories?

Tags: shell, command-line, replace

I want to search for `var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");` and replace it with 'google analytics code' in all the files which are under home directory.

In php eclips editor it shows all the occurrences but cannot replace all at a time.
So, I am thinking to use shell script for it.

/home/project/news4u/web is my rot directory and how to use `sed` command for achieving it.

I tried `sed s/'var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");'/'google analytics' *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU sed it has `-i` option that can edit files in-place.
And if you have `bash` you need to enable globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

because afair `sed` can walk through directory tree itself

```
sed -i.bak "s@'var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : "http://www.");'@'google analytics'@" **
```

`-i.bak` will backup each file with `.bak` extension. It is usefull if somthing goes wrong.

I advise you to check at first with "dry" run without `-i` option on some specific file if everything works fine and only after that to run it with `-i`.

ps. If you don't have GNU sed or bash or both you can do it more complicated, but POSIX compatbile way:

```
find . -type f -exec sed "s@'var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : "http://www.");'@'google analytics'@" {} > {}.tmp \; -exec mv {}.tmp {} \;
```

Comment: I tried sed "s@'var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : "http://www.");'@'google analytics'@" ** 

It is giving error sed: read error on CVS: Is a directory..
dir structure is as below : /apps/module/alert/template/{template1.php, template2.php..}
There is also a cvs folder under template /template/CVS.

Comment: try this one `find . -type f -exec sed "s@'var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : "http://www.");'@'google analytics'@" {} \;`

Comment: this below replaces 'sed -i s/gaJsHost/google-analytic/ <sourcefile> <dest-file>'

Now I need is a recursive call which put source-name and dest-name as same.

If passed maually like sed -i s/manoj/gaJsHost/ emp.php emp.php it works well

Comment: `find /home/project/news4u/web -type f -exec sed -i s/gaJsHost/google-analytic/ {} \;`

Comment: how to use the same for string with " and ' into it. for example
find /home/project/news4u/web  -type f -exec sed -i s/var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.")/google-analytic/ {} \;

should we enclose the source string in single quotes ??

Comment: You need to quote sed command with double quotes and escape all double quotes inside it: `find /home/project/news4u/web -type f -exec sed -i "s/var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"ssl."; : \"\")/google-analytic/" {} \;`

Comment: This...
find /home/project/news4u/apps/frontend/module/alerts/templates/testing -type f -exec sed -i "s/var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://ssl.\" : \"http://www.\")/google-analytic/" {} \;

is giving an error 'sed: -e expression #1, char 71: unknown option to `s'

Comment: if there are NO ' or " used in search string, it is working fine.

Comment: Looks like you have `/` in your pattern which is also is command delimiter. So you need to escape `/` inside of pattern or change delimiter like that: `find /home/project/news4u/web -type f -exec sed -i "s@var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) \? \"ssl."; : \"\")@google-analytic@" {} \;`. ps. add the escape symbol before `?` too.

Comment: `var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");`

should ssl." is to be ssl.\"

Comment: is this right ..  `-type f -exec sed -i "s/var gaJsHost = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) \? \"https:\/\/ssl.\" : \"http:\/\/www.\")/goo/" {} \;`